# only <a> tag execute from html content in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My problem is only execute  tag from html content in rails.

I'm using raw, sanitize but all html tag executed

Example

`@input = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a> <b>bold</b> <i>bat</i>'
 <%=raw @input%>
 <%=sanitize @input%>`
 
there are same output: [go](http://www.example.com/) **bold** *bat*

my propose is output: [go](http://www.example.com/) `<b>bold</b> <i>bat</i>`

I implementing hash tag like facebook, but user input not safe many hash tag and many html tags

any idea?
thank you

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with this and the following will help:

```
@input = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a>'
@input += '<b>bold</b> <i>bat</i>'.encode {xml: :text}
```

This will format the HTML special characters as raw symbols. More at [the docs for String#encode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-encode).

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
<% @input = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a>'.html_safe+'<b>bold</b> <i>bat</i>' %>
<%= raw @input %>
```

Comment: a lot of <a> tags
example `<% @input = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a><a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a> <b>bold</b> <a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a> <i>bat</i> <a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a>' %>`

Comment: I didn't understand? What do you mean by "a lot of a tags"?

Comment: @УуганбаярГ.: Ok, if you can show how you're generating it then maybe we can find out how to solve this. Can you post your code with the information on how you're generating these tags?

Comment: @УуганбаярГ.: How can this be a user input? You should clearly state such things in your question upfront so that we can consider other approaches to solve such issues. Can you please update your code with what's actually happening in your code?

Comment: I implementing hash tag like facebook, but user input not safe many hash tag and many html tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
@input = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">go</a>'.html_safe
@input += ' <b>bold</b> <i>bat</i>'
<%= @input %>
```

Comment: Using `link_to` is preferable to banging out raw HTML.